# How can I have git ignore local changes to a specific file, without modifying the .gitignore?

Tags: git, vagrant, gitignore, vagrantfile

My specific situation is this: I am working with a team on a git repo. We are using a vagrant machine, so in the git repo there is a Vagrantfile. I would like to modify my vagrant machine's configuration file to use specific amounts of memory and CPU cores, but i don't want to force all the other users of this repo to have these modifications. We DO want to have this Vagrantfile in the repo, so i can't add it to the .gitignore. I don't want to have to keep undoing and redoing my edits every time i commit my changes.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to use version control to solve a configuration problem.  Why don't you have your vagrant file include some custom local configuration file (if it exists).

Answer (score 4):

You can try `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`.
This will assume that there is no change on this file, so it wont push it.

If you want to track it again, use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: `assume-unchanged` is not for ignoring files, you're making a promise to Git that you *will not* change the file.  Violating that promise leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to your own `$HOME/.gitignore` file, unfortunately I don't think that affects files that are already version controled by git.

I usually do `<some_file>_example` and ignore `<some_file>`, which might be an option in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an architecture issue, not easily addressed by Git itself.  In my team we have addressed similar issues by having each developer maintain their own cloned copies of Git repos on shared computers, where...

```
C:\GitRepos\<developer>\
```

...would be each developer's Git working directory on the shared asset, and...

```
C:\GitRepos\<developer>\<repo>
```

...would be where each repo folder for each developer would be located.  In this way, anything that needs to be specific to a developer, but not included in the repo, can be saved at `C:\GitRepos\<developer>\`.  I hope this helps. :)